# Filter r shiny boxplot by input value

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to take an input value from ui.r, in this case filterValue, and filter my dataframe (mpgData) by the input value. Then I want to create a boxplot of two other variables.

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Filtered Boxplot"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("filterValue", "Filter Variable:",
                list("value1" = "value1", "value2" = "value2", ..."value100" = "value100"))

    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
        list("Tier" = "tier", 
        "Second_variable" = "second_variable"))
  ),

    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption")),
      plotOutput("mpgPlot")
    )
  ))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

data <- read.csv("csv_file", header=TRUE, fill= TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
mpgData <- data
mpgData$tier <- factor(mpgData$tier, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  newData <- reactive({
    a <- subset(mpgData, column_name %in% input$filterValue)
    a <- droplevels(a)
  return(a)
  })

  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste("column_name ~", input$variable)
  })

  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })

  output$mpgPlot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(as.formula(formulaText()), 
            data = newData)
  })
})
```

I am getting this error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :    cannot coerce class
>   ""reactive"" to a data.frame

Am I missing a step of converting my csv upload into a dataframe?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data = newData()` at `output$mpgPlot`?

Comment: Like this:
    
    output$mpgPlot <- renderPlot({
  boxplot(as.formula(formulaText()), 
    data = newData())
   })